# SQLite 3 не видит столбец

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('base.db')
sql = connection.cursor()

sql.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT)
''')

connection.commit()

login = input('Login: ')
password = input('Password: ')

sql.execute('SELECT login FROM users')

if sql.fetchone() is None:
    sql.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?)', (login, password))
    connection.commit()
```

При попытке выполнить код, выдает ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 16, in 
sql.execute('SELECT login FROM users')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: login

А самый интерес в том, что ошибка эта только у меня на пк. Спрашивал у друзей - у них все отлично, сам проверял с телефона - также все нормально. Почему именно на моем пк код не работает? Файл базы данных создан с расширением db и находится в той же директории где и код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` не будет создавать таблицу, если с таким именем уже есть. А значит, колонки в ней останутся те, которые были. И далеко не факт, что там будет login/password (эта таблица могла остаться от предыдущих экспериментов). Подключайтесь внучную и смотрите, [что там да как](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-describe-table/):

```
sqlite3 base.db
> .schema users
```